# Test/Production configuration for Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, soap, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebSite project with WebJob project accosiated with it. The WebJob project needs to connect to external SOAP service. AS a result I have to put in the app.config the following block:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_MyExternalClassName">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="<<external URL>>" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_MyExternalClassName" contract="xxxxx" name="WSHttpBinding_MyExternalClassName" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

The problem is that I need to change value of `<<external URL>>` in "endpoint" node for different deployment scenarios - testing and production.
WebJob SDK seems to take Connection strings and app settigns from parent application, but what abount this specific SOAP-related service setting ? 
How can I manage testing/production scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the soap URL appSettings section inside web.config. Then read it using ConfigurationManager or CloudConfigurationManager. Obviously you have to manually set the url in code when you create the wcf client.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="soapurl" value="http://..." />
  </appSettings>
```